# Table of contents appears after each slide

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I have a problem, in my beamer presentation the table of contents appears after each slide.
I want the table of contents to appear only in the first slide without repeating after each slide, please I would appreciate any help, I tried many commands to stop the repetition but no result and it still appears after each slide after I enter \section appears automatically the table of contents. Where am I wrong?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{multimedia}

\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.16}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}{\textbf{Table of contents}}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}
%\frame{\titlepage}
    

\section{Author and committee}
\begin{frame}   
\end{frame}


\section{References}
\begin{frame}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing the frame with the table of content into `\AtBeginSection[]{...}` it will be repeated at the start of every section. If you only want to show the table of contents once, remove the `\AtBeginSection[]{...}` around it:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multimedia}
%\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

%\AtBeginSection[]
%{
\begin{frame}{\textbf{Table of contents}}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%}

\section{Author and committee}
\begin{frame}   
\end{frame}

\section{References}
\begin{frame}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, you saved me!
I didn't think it could be that simple, I tried everything, but I didn't think about that.
Thank you again

Comment: @AngelinaMaria You're welcome!